In iText is it possible to create a custom font with different stylings and make it work with .setBold and .setItalic?
So I have this code
PdfFont customFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont("/templates/NunitoSans.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
PdfFont customFontBold = PdfFontFactory.createFont("/templates/NunitoSansBold.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
PdfFont customFontBoldItalic = PdfFontFactory.createFont("/templates/NunitoSansBoldItalic.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
PdfFont customFontItalic = PdfFontFactory.createFont("/templates/NunitoSansItalic.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);

right now I track in the parser whether I am bold or italic and if so I have to use
setFont to the appropriate value for the combination
is it possible to just have have setFont which understands that it can be bold, italic or both using .setBold or .setItalic and have it choose the proper font?

Have you tried working with setFontFamily in combination with setFontProvider?

do you have a code example for that?

You can use a FontProvider. That allows you to first use the FontFamily setter to select a font family like Verdana or NunitoSans and then use the FONT_WEIGHT and FONT_STYLE properties to select bold and italic styles.
For example:
try (
    PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(TARGET);
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
    Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
) {
    FontProvider fontProvider = new FontProvider();
    fontProvider.addSystemFonts();
    document.setFontProvider(fontProvider);

    Div div = new Div();
    div.setFontFamily("Verdana");
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
    paragraph.add("Regular");
    div.add(paragraph);
    paragraph = new Paragraph();
    paragraph.setProperty(Property.FONT_WEIGHT, "700");
    paragraph.add("bold");
    div.add(paragraph);
    paragraph = new Paragraph();
    paragraph.setProperty(Property.FONT_STYLE, "italic");
    paragraph.add("Italic");
    div.add(paragraph);
    paragraph = new Paragraph();
    paragraph.setProperty(Property.FONT_WEIGHT, "700");
    paragraph.setProperty(Property.FONT_STYLE, "italic");
    paragraph.add("Bold & Italic");
    div.add(paragraph);
    document.add(div);
}

This creates (if the Verdana font family is installed):

FontProvider also has other methods (addStandardPdfFonts, addDirectory, and many addFont overloads) to add fonts, have a look at the JavaDocs.

Tested with the current iText 8.0.4-SNAPSHOT.

that's adding system fonts, what if I just want to add TTF files?

See my final paragraph: use one of the many addFont overloads.
